# How to display url's as text, not number from DB?

Tags: python, django

I am new in Python, I have a problem with the way an URL is displayed in the address bar. For now the URL is localhost:8000/1/ I would like the URL to be  localhost:8000/name of a entry in the field/ Can somebody please give me a hint.

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,  url 
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', 'papers.views.index', name='index'),
 url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'papers.views.detail', name='detail'),
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
 ]   

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

papers/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question


def index(request):
   latest_question_list = Question.objects.all
   context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
   return render(request, 'papers/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'papers/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

papers/templates/papers/detail.html

```
{% extends "master2.html"  %}
{% block h1 %}  

<div class="center">
    <h4>{{question.naslov}} </h4>
    <p>{{question.opsirnije_text}}</p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
{% block title  %} Detail {% endblock %}
```

papers/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
  naslov = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  opis = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  datum_objave = models.DateTimeField('date published')
  opsirnije_text = models.TextField(max_length=20000)

def __str__(self):             
    return self.naslov

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.datum_objave >= timezone.now() -  datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: The URL is what you make it. If you want to use a field other than the primary key, then just do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface:** First off, let's clarify the *direction* in which things are mapped. You're not *assigning* URLs to objects in your database; requests can be for **any** URL, and then Django has to *figure out* what that means, and how to reply.
**i.e.** it's `{url} -> looks up object`, not `{object} -> has a URL`

Here's your URL route:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'papers.views.detail', name='detail'),
```

And here's where you're handling it:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
```

So what happens is when someone types in `localhost:8000/34/` for example, it matches the regex rule "base URL followed by numbers". If you want to change that to "base URL followed by a name", you can do so:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_name>[\w_-]+)/$', 'papers.views.detail', name='detail'),
```

(Specifically here, letters, or the hyphen or underscore character; modify the regex according to what your "question name" looks like.)

You'll then need to deal with the fact that your handler has to accept names:

```
def detail(request, question_name):
    question = Question.objects.get(naslov=question_name)
```

The limitation here is that the `.get` query has to result in a unique result; if it's at all possible for multiple questions to have the same name, you'll have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first change the URL pattern for `papers.view.detail` so it doesn't just match integers -- something like `\w+` instead of `[0-9]+`. You probably want to rename the capturing group, too. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html.

Then, you need to change the `detail` method take an  argument corresponding to the capturing group's name, and to query for the object by that argument (which I guess is the `naslov` field?).